# Is a Session-Less Design feasible?

Tags: http, session, authentication

Just brainstorming some ideas for a Web App I'm building soon.

One of the cornerstones of the Web is Session Handling: Have the user log in, send a cookie with magic binary encoded pixie dust, trust the user blindly afterwards.

I just wonder if it's feasible to completely eliminate 'traditional' sessions for a web app that would normally use it, e.g. an online store.

The idea would be to have a 'server side session' that doesn't use the SessionID or anything, but the username instead. So there is exactly 1 session per user, not more. That would allow stuff like a persistent shopping cart to work.

Authentication would be handled similar to how Web Services work: Expect HTTP Digest authentication on every single page view.

Ignoring the fact that anonymous visitors would have to be handled differently, do you think this approach would be feasible? Or would the additional traffic/load for constant authentication be a deal-breaker in the long run?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for serverside sessions instead of cookie-based sessions. The session state is stored in a database. Then on every page load you can consult the session database to pull all appropriate user related information out. Does that sound like what you mean?

Comment: @drachenstern Yes and no. The thing with sessions is that the client has a session id that allows him to completely circumvent authorization. Essentially my idea is a Session where the UserName is the SessionID.

Comment: ~ I think you miss something fundamental here ... you have to have the authorization token with the session id on most of them, so for instance, here's my auth token for my current web-app `45BE8B86E43F81228307F9B8D8F1B37D68F110295DC3875B977AA7CDC11B37628F36
F6852F21BCFB16E7FC16D057603C32431425603AC11D333661329EE34BD09084917D
9145FC2A63C63D82E3A2C5259DD3E67899C564110FA1D1AC4A623553C32D7402819C
5668EABC9C4A2A386FE008EACAB822D750E80A6F58BF50CC9AFD15D7CA2D5784B723
36FFC4F1CF08FB1C9AFBF98301942B72983EF273CA30A376E1D110B1` (Granted, I'm using ASP.NET WebForms so there's that)

Comment: Or are you assuming they will be so malicious that they will copy the authkey and the sessionid from another computer? Because you can't really randomly stumble onto a working pair of those two, can you?

Comment: @drachenstern the idea is to protect the user from other malicious users in their network. Granted, users who are subject to traffic sniffing have other problems, but I'm still interested in ways a web app can protect it's users if it makes sense.

Comment: But username as ID would be a really bad idea since you can easily guess it and hijack the session that way. Thus the need for those lengthy hash strings as ids usually in some kind of pair.

Answer (score 9):

First off, we don't use sessions at all.

We found that utilizing session complicated the code without any benefit.  There are only two reasons to even consider using session state.  The first is to reduce the amount of traffic to your sql server..  However, with load balanced web servers etc, session has to be stored in a sql server... Which kind of eliminates it's first point.  But it's worse than that as the session has to be retrieved, deserialized, serialized, and stored on every single page load.

The second reason is to keep from having the browser pass the user id back to the application on each request.  However, "session hijacking" is a fairly easy trick to pull off and is rarely taken into account.

So, instead, we use a highly encrypted cookie with non-guessable values that indicate exactly who the user is.  We've coupled this with a changing, non-guessable, request id and have eliminated both session state (and it's unnecessary overhead) while at the same time improving security all around.

Can the cookie be stolen?  Sure, but it has a very limited life that is the amount of time between two postbacks.  Which means it will be found to have been compromised rather quickly.

So, I wouldn't say sessions are a "corner stone" of the web.  Rather I'd say they are crutches that are often used improperly and should be avoided for both security and performance reasons.

All of that said, the only way you are going to tie this to a user id is if you force your users to login/create account prior to shopping.. Which no one is going to do unless they have no other choice but to be on your site.

Oh, and don't take my word for it:

[4GuysFromRolla.com -> Session variables are evil.](https://web.archive.org/web/20150128015317/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com:80/webtech/faq/Advanced/faq4.shtml)
[aps.net -> Are session variables still evil?](http://forums.asp.net/t/317388.aspx)
[Scott Hansleman -> Moving Viewstate to Session](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MovingViewStateToTheSessionObjectAndMoreWrongheadedness.aspx)  Pay attention to the part in bold covering memory consumption and it's ability to stay around for way too long.
[Coding Horror -> Your Session has timed out](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/your-session-has-timed-out.html)  This details just some of the problems associated with even using session
[Wikipedia -> Session Hijacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking)  What list would be complete without a link to wikipedia?

Comment: So, if someone is using your site, and the latest encrypted key is "1234", then goes away for a few hours, when they come back, will that key still be valid?  If so, then how are you not just as exposed as a standard .Net session other than changing it every request?  Regardless, there is a key that can be taken from 1 machine to another and activity will resume as normal, right?  I understand that if the original user continues to use the site, you'll know that someone is trying to hack you, and this "security hole" has been minimized, but it still exists, right?

Comment: @Matt: First we tell the cookies to expire after a very small time period.  Second, we have an encrypted last seen at value inside the cookie that we test on ourselves.  This allows us to force the cookie expiration in the event it's replayed.  Of course, if they steal the last one then they could replay it up to a few minutes later.  However, this would take have to be a highly targeted attack for it to work.

Comment: I see.  How do you deal with expired cookies then?  I'm thinking along the lines of someone leaving their computer while in the middle of a task, coming back, and then their cookie has expired and so their work would be lost.  Of course, your site requirements might render that question moot.  I don't know anything about your site/biz requirements.  Just curious.

Comment: @Matt: Our site works on fairly atomic operations, meaning the amount of possible work lost due to expiration is very small.  This is tempered by the sensitivity of the data in question.  For us it's better to kick them out and have them log back in than to leave the window open.

Comment: Fair enough -- thanks Chris!  It's nice to get a good understanding of technique like yours, and also the limitations, so that I can know if and when to use it.  Thanks for your time and explanations.

Comment: "We've coupled this with a changing, non-guessable, request id" - what happens if the user opens a second window? How do you create a user id? You are just using the user id as the session identifier and created lots of headaches for yourselves and your users.

Comment: @symcbean: In our case, the security needs outweigh any perceived need to open multiple windows.

Comment: @Chris: You really believe this enhances security? LOL

Answer (score 0):

REST-like implementations such ASP.NET MVC do not require session state at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should just use sessions. Even if its your own session implementation: eg. cookie contains random key used to store information the server. A cookie must be used or you will have to encode all links on the site with a query parameter that specifies the key -- bad idea!

I would then store the "session key", or what every you want to call it, with the persons username in the database.

When a user logs in to your site simply restore their previous "session".

Other then the query parameter option, which is a bad idea, you can track users by IP address. But this again is a horrible idea! Eg. many buildings have a limited number of Internet IPs and many times more internal computers.

There is no good way to track a user without using cookies.

Yes maybe you can use HTTP authentication but why bother? You are just going to introduce new issues and put limitations on your UI.

Comment: I wouldn't have to encode any links as there is exactly one session per user, and I know who the user is because they have to authenticate for each request - so I have a 'good' key already.

Comment: If you don't use cookies though won't you have to expect the http authentication to always be sent with every request so you know the person is? I haven't tried this before. You will want all requests to go through a secure connection. Can't use http since, I believe, http authentication is sent in plain-text on every request. Additionally you can't provide a way to logout.

Answer (score 0):

That actually is pretty much what a traditional session does -- provide a unique identifier to distinguish a browser "session", all you are doing is tying it to username rather then a random variable.

I would say just be very careful of how you generate your token, if it is reproducible you could easily accomplishes the goal of a session fixation attack by generating someone elses session and jamming it into a cookie. That is the reason that sessions are usually a random unique value.

Comment: The idea is to not have a token. Nothing that gets sent to the client - no cookie, no fancy URL, nothing at all. Instead, HTTP Authentication for every request.

Comment: HTTP Authentication sends its own stuff on every request.  You just don't mess with it, the server and client do.

Answer (score 0):

> The idea would be to have a 'server side session' that doesn't use the SessionID or anything, but the username instead. So there is exactly 1 session per user, not more. That would allow stuff like a persistent shopping cart to work.

That's just a session, but using the username as the session identifier - which is going to cause all sorts of problems - its open to replay attacks even if you encrypt it. You can't change the encrpytion per-request because that will break when the user opens a second window or presses the back button.

You can't rely on the client address - multiple users may share a NAT address, the same user may access your site from behind a cluster of load-balanced proxies.

> like a persistent shopping cart

...implies that you have server-side data for the customer - since the size of this data will vary, you can't store it in the URL nor in a cookie.

> Expect HTTP Digest authentication on every single page view.

That presupposes that you create accounts for every user, and that you're not concerned about the impact of the same user id being used by different clients. I don't think that this would require significantly more processing than a conventional session - *but its still web-based session management* with a different set of problems and vulnerabilities compared to the conventional approach.